# Find a subarray of m*m (2<=m<n) having largest sum; out of an n*n int array(having +ve, -ve, 0s)

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have written a solution for the above problem but can someone please suggest an optimized way.
I have traversed through the array for count(2 to n) where count is finding subarrays of size count*count.

```
int n = 5;      //Size of array, you may take a dynamic array as well
int a[5][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},{2,4,7,-2,1},{4,3,9,9,1},{5,2,6,8,0},{5,4,3,2,1}};
int max = 0;
int **tempStore, size;

for(int count = 2; count < n; count++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= (n-count); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= (n-count); j++)
        {
            int **temp = new int*[count]; 
            for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                temp[i] = new int[count];
            }

            for(int k = 0; k < count; k++)
            {
                for(int l = 0; l <count; l++)
                {
                    temp[k][l] = a[i+k][j+l];
                }
            }
            //printing fetched array
            int sum = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < count; k++)
            {
                for(int l = 0; l <count; l++)
                {
                    sum += temp[k][l];
                    cout<<temp[k][l]<<" ";
                }cout<<endl;
            }cout<<"Sum = "<<sum<<endl;
            if(sum > max)
            {
                max = sum;
                size = count;
                tempStore = new int*[count]; 
                for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                    tempStore[i] = new int[count];
                }
                //Locking the max sum array
                for(int k = 0; k < count; k++)
                {
                    for(int l = 0; l <count; l++)
                    {
                        tempStore[k][l] = temp[k][l];
                    }
                }
            }
            //printing finished
            cout<<"------------------\n";
            //Clear temp memory
            for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                delete[] temp[i];
            }
            delete[] temp;
        }
    }
}

cout<<"Max sum is = "<<max<<endl;
for(int k = 0; k < size; k++)
{
    for(int l = 0; l <size; l++)
    {
        cout<<tempStore[k][l]<<" ";
    }cout<<endl;
}cout<<"-------------------------";

//Clear tempStore memory
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    delete[] tempStore[i];
    }
delete[] tempStore;
```

Example:

1 2 3 4  5

2 4 7 -2 1

4 3 9 9  1

5 2 6 8  0

5 4 3 2  1

Output:
Max sum is = 71

2 4 7 -2

4 3 9 9

5 2 6 8

5 4 3 2

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: I guess your question is more applicable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: (Also, format this properly please.)

Comment: C or C++ any would do.
Moreover, I have not put complete code here for review, I just want a better solution.
-Thanks

Comment: C and C++ are *different* languages. The more elegant solution will in fact look very different in each. So which is the one you need?

Comment: your code looks so messy. please try to clean it up - are the statements within the code snippets comments in the code?

Comment: Your requirement is not at all clear, can you clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (using naive approach, will be easier to get the idea):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include<vector>
using namespace std; 
int main( )
{ 
    int n = 5; //Size of array, you may take a dynamic array as well
    int a[5][5] = 
      {{2,1,8,9,0},{2,4,7,-2,1},{5,4,3,2,1},{3,4,9,9,2},{5,2,6,8,0}};
    int sum, partsum;
    int i, j, k, m;
    sum = -999999; // presume minimum part sum 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        partsum = 0;
        m = sizeof(a[i])/sizeof(int);
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            partsum += a[i][j];
        }
        if (partsum > sum) {
            k = i;
            sum = partsum;
        }
    }
    // print subarray having largest sum
    m = sizeof(a[k])/sizeof(int); // m needs to be recomputed
    for (j = 0; j < m - 1; j++) {
        cout << a[k][j] << ", ";
    }
    cout << a[k][m - 1] <<"\nmax part sum = " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it is not giving me desired output.
I have added an example in the question now.

Comment: Edited, had one problem, m needs to be recomputed before last loop

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem best solved using Dynamic Programming (DP) or memoization.

Assuming n is significantly large, you will find that recalculating the sum of every possible combination of matrix will take too long, therefore if you could reuse previous calculations that would make everything much faster.

The idea is to start with the smaller matrices and calculate sum of the larger one reusing the precalculated value of the smaller ones.

```
long long *sub_solutions = new long long[n*n*m];

#define at(r,c,i) sub_solutions[((i)*n + (r))*n + (c)]

// Winner:
unsigned int w_row = 0, w_col = 0, w_size = 0;

// Fill first layer:
for ( int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
        at(r, c, 0) = data[r][c];
        if (data[r][c] > data[w_row][w_col]) { 
            w_row = r;
            w_col = c;
        }           
    }
}

// Fill remaining layers.
for ( int size = 1; size < m; size++) {
    for ( int row = 0; row < n-size; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < n-size; col++) {
            long long sum = data[row+size][col+size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                sum += data[row+size][col+i];
                sum += data[row+i][col+size];
            }
            sum += at(row, col, size-1); // Reuse previous solution.
            at(row, col, size) = sum;
            if (sum > at(w_row, w_col, w_size)) { // Could optimize this part if you only need the sum.
                w_row = row;
                w_col = col;
                w_size = size;
            }
        }
    }
}

// The largest sum is of the sub_matrix starting a w_row, w_col, and has dimensions w_size+1.
long long largest = at(w_row, w_col, w_size);

delete [] sub_solutions;
```

This algorithm has complexity: `O(n*n*m*m)` or more precisely: `0.5*n*(n-1)*m*(m-1)`. (Now I haven't tested this so please let me know if there are any bugs.)

Answer (score 0):

With a cumulative sum, you may compute partial sum in constant time

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>
compute_cumulative(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& m)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> res(m.size() + 1, std::vector<int>(m.size() + 1));

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != m.size(); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j != m.size(); ++j) {
            res[i + 1][j + 1] = m[i][j] - res[i][j]
                        + res[i + 1][j] + res[i][j + 1];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int compute_partial_sum(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& cumulative, std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t size)
{
    return cumulative[i][j] + cumulative[i + size][j + size]
           - cumulative[i][j + size] - cumulative[i + size][j];

}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/IOiL8o)